# Swift - UILabel from URL

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsurl

I wanted to know if it's possible to load the text in a label from a URL.

I was going to try and use NSURL to pull in a .txt file stored online.

Would anyone know how to implement this with swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use sessions, you can also use the simpler NSURLConnection Class, something like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt")

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))




    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        // Do stuff on the UI thread
        self.textField.text = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        return
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Would altering the encoding in the code allow you to read an RTF file?

Comment: No worries, I found out that you can use the label's formatting to work with the text file so really rich text isn't necessary. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Yes, I know how to do it. However, you haven't exerted any effort whatsoever to solve your problem yourself.

Search on NSURLConnection. Unless you need https or login, you could use the class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, which is very easy to use. You should be able to find examples of using it on the net.

You could also use a library like Alamofire. That makes it even easier.

Comment: thanks. I got it sorted from some of the other answers though :)